# return nil vs return false in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

So, I have this code from a colleague with lots of `return false` and `return true`.

For example this method:

```
def has_only_one_uploaded_image?
  return false if images.size > 1
  method_here
end
```

If I remove the `false` as the return value, will it still work if I use it from other conditions?

like in this method...

```
def commission_plan_product_available?
  (has_only_one_uploaded_image? ||
    (has_many_images? && images_are_saved?))
end
```

I'm confused as to when to use the proper `boolean` return and when I should not.

I'm new to Ruby (not sure if `nil` can be also `false` in conditionals, please bear with me. Thank you.

Can someone shed some light please?

Comment: most of the predicate method(contain `?` like `has_only_one_uploaded_image?`) should return `boolean`

Comment: In my recent code, I removed the `false`. I retained just this... `return if images.size > 1`, so it will return `nil` if it satisfied the condition. other methods like `(has_many_images? && images_are_saved?))` will return `boolean` cc: @RajarshiDas

Comment: So @RajarshiDas you mean other methods should return `boolean`, because `nil || nil` won't be good. I see.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`nil` is "falsey", and if used directly in a conditional - or combined using logical operators `&&`, `||` etc, will behave the same as `false`, and your uses of it should work as you intend.

However, it is usually better practice to return `true` or `false` values from methods that behave like booleans. There is little or no extra cost, `true` and `false` are the same sort of thing internally to Ruby as `nil` (a simple VALUE with fixed content, it is not resolved as a pointer).

Returning `nil` conditionally makes more sense when you have a method which either returns an object you have asked for, or "nothing" for some good reason (e.g. you ask for a User with a specific id, but there is no such User).

If in doubt, think of how you would document the method. If you would need to explain to a user why it returns  `true` or `nil`, and the explanation for this choice seems convoluted, then it would be much simpler to do what is expected and return `true` or `false`

For a very few methods, it may even make sense to return `true`, `false` or `nil` - the last one being essentially "I don't know". A method that caches the output from another method that returns `true` or `false` might do this.

Comment: Neil makes a bunch of good points. I would add that `return false` makes it easier to see your intent in the source code of the method. ` return false if images.size > 1` reads more readily than `return if images.size > 1`, in my opinion: in one the intent appears to be notifying the operation did not happen, and the other looks like you simply wanted to terminate execution.